# Select data from multiple tables and grouping in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a part of an assignment I am working on.
I have a database named `COMPANY`, where there are 6 tables

- `EMPLOYEE`
- `DEPARTMENTS`
- `DEPT_EMP`
- `TITLES`
- `SALARIES`
- `DEPT_MANAGER`

Now I have to list the number of Engineers in each department.

I came up with the following query:

```
select departments.dept_name as Department_name,
       count(titles.title) as No_Of_Engineers
from departments,
     titles
where titles.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
  and dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
  and titles.title like "% engineer %"
group by departments.dept_no;
```

But this gives me the error

> Unknown column 'dept_emp.emp_no' in 'where clause'

But my `dept_emp` table has a column named `emp_no`.
Can anyone see the error in this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no dept_emp in the from clause. I.e. the WHERE clause looks like there are 3 tables involved, but you're only selecting from 2 tables.

Comment: `...from departments,
     titles, dept_emp...` shouldn't there be `dept_emp` table in the from clause?

Comment: @jarlh Is it compulsory ? Because I don't want `emp_no` in my result.

Comment: @1000111Ah, I got it. Thanks :)

Comment: I can't answer that question because I don't know the tables and the data. You don't have to include columns from all tables in the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a join to `dept_emp`:

```
select departments.dept_name as Department_name,
       count(titles.title) as No_Of_Engineers
from departments
     INNER JOIN dept_emp
      ON(dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no)
     INNER JOIN titles
      ON(titles.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no)
WHERE titles.title like "% engineer %"
group by departments.dept_no;
```

I've also corrected your joins, please try to avoid the use of implicit join syntax(comma separated) and use the proper syntax of joins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why am I needed to avoid implicit joins ?

Comment: They are unreadable and may lead to mistakes in the future! Perhaps when joining two/three tables you can still understand, but when another programmer will try to work a code he didn't built, containing like 6 or more tables, it will be very hard to understand! And don't let me talk about `LEFT JOIN`s with the plus sign . It's a bad habit and you should get used to the proper syntax.

Comment: That's becuase you probably gave the wrong name. Look at `departments` table, what's the name of `department_number` column ?

Comment: The column name was `dept_no`. But I've fixed the error bygrouping them by `department_name`.
Thank you very much for the help !